# How to emulate an hash table in SQF?

Tags: sqf

FYI: [SQF is a programming language](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax) for the computer game series Arma.

The main data types of SQF [are documented](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Data_Types#Available_Types) and the list does not include an hash table (or dictionary).

One way to have a hash table is to create a Game Logic in the `mission.sqm` (e.g. named `logic1`), and use `setVariable` and `getVariable` on it, e.g.

```
logic1 setVariable ["variable1", 1];
_a = logic1 getVariable "variable1";
```

However, this requires an extra array associated with it to track the list of used keys, e.g.

```
logic1Vars = [];
logic1 setVariable ["variable1", 1];
logic1Vars pushBack "variable1";

logic1 setVariable ["variable1", nil];
logic1Vars = logic1Vars - ["variable1"];
```

(or is there a way to get the list of variables?)

Another way (that is possible but I haven't tried) is to implement an hash table. That obviously takes an extra effort because implementing a good table is not easy.

But maybe I am missing something: is there an idiomatic way to have an hash table in SQF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [allVariables](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/allVariables) to retrieve the Number of keys in a Namespace.

To create a Namespace you can use a Logic or a Location or a SimpleObject. See how CBA does it https://github.com/CBATeam/CBA_A3/blob/master/addons/common/fnc_createNamespace.sqf.

Generally a Location or SimpleObject is more Performance friendly than using a GameLogic. You should keep that in Mind.

But what you are probably searching for is the allVariables command which returns all Variables in a Namespace(Hashtable).

You can also use [`getVariable ARRAY`](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/getVariable) to set a default Value in case the Namespace doesn't contain the Key you want to read.

CBA also has [`Hashes`](https://github.com/CBATeam/CBA_A3/tree/master/addons/hashes) they behave like a Map. Not like a hashTable (The keys are not hashed) also it's SQF code instead of Engine code so it is slightly slower.

Also (don't have enough reputation to comment)
You don't need all of this:

```
_vars = _logic getVariable "_VARIABLES";
_vars pushBack "variable1";
_logic setVariable ["_VARIABLES", _vars];
```

_vars will be a reference to the Array and pushBack will add an element to that Array you are referring to. so pushBack is already modifying `_VARIABLES`. No need to set it again.

Comment: `allVariables` returns lower-cased variables names. I assume keys are case-insentitive, right?.  Finally, can you provide a minimal code example using a `SimpleObject`?

Answer (score 3):

Though this is an old question I'd like to list a new answer that you can now natively create a [HashMap in SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/HashMap) since Arma 3 version 2.01 using the [`createHashMap`](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/createHashMap) command.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create an hash table without having to create it in the `mission.sqm` is to create it scripting. Specifically, it is possible to write

```
allHashes = createGroup west;  // somewhere once; `west` or `east` does not matter here.

_logic = allHashes createUnit ["LOGIC", [0,0,0], [], 0, "NONE"];
_logicVars = [];
```

this still  requires the list of variables, and thus does not encapsulate the whole hash table in a single object. One way to achieve the hash table logic in a single object is to use

```
_logic = allHashes createUnit ["LOGIC", [0,0,0], [], 0, "NONE"];
_logic setVariable ["_VARIABLES", []];
```

and use

```
_logic setVariable ["variable1", 1];
_vars = _logic getVariable "_VARIABLES";
_vars pushBack "variable1";
_logic setVariable ["_VARIABLES", _vars];
```

This can be encapsulated in a function, but still needs 4 lines of code to get the whole thing...

Comment: I wouldn't complain about 4-lines of code, a complete hash implementation in C can be 100 times that amount (and be quite efficient on rehashing, load factor handling, etc..)